# CHECK an optimized query plan

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, check-constraints

I'm suprised by the behaviour of SQL Server 2008(r2).

I've defined a table with a column like this:

```
ex int not null default 1 check (ex = 1)
```

And I expected queries like

```
select *
from t20130603_b
where ex = 0
```

to have query plans where there's no rows fetched, just a constant value used (since ex = 0 is impossible).

But there are (full scan).

Did I get/do something wrong?

Comment: Does the query get auto parameterized? Is the check constraint trusted?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't get any of your two questions. The query is written as I put it there. I have no idea what "trusted" means here.

Comment: Haven't time for a full answer. Suspect the issue will be auto parameterization. Have a look at the XML for the plan and see if it references a parameter called `@1`. If so then auto parameterization was attempted and if successful it was compiled for a generic parameter rather than the specific literal value. RE trusted constraints you can tell this from `is_not_trusted` column in `sys.check_constraints`. If not trusted the QO can't use them for simplification. Happens if the check constraint was re-enabled without `CHECK` option to verify existing data.

Comment: @Martin It's looked complicated, but I got what you point were and re-ran the query with OPTION (RECOMPILE) and this time it went just fine. I actually added the column like this: alter table t20130603_b add ex int not null default 1 check (ex = 1). How do I force trust then? (you could put your comment as an answer as it deserve to be validated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities. The plan may have been auto parameterized or the check constraint may not be trusted.

```
CREATE TABLE t20130603_b
  (
     ex INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 CONSTRAINT ck CHECK (ex = 1)
  )

/*Plan shows table scan*/
SELECT *
FROM   t20130603_b
WHERE  ex = 0
```

[image: Plan 1]

In SQL Server 2012 the text in the graphical plan shows that auto parameterization was attempted (the text is `ex = @1`) on previous versions you may need to look at the XML version of the plan. Because the literal `0` was replaced with a parameter `@1` before compilation the contradiction with the check constraint cannot be detected.

More details about auto parameterization [are here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/01/11/4-0-query-parameterization.aspx). That article mentions that queries with `IN Expressions` don't get auto parameterized. Trying the below

```
SELECT *
FROM   t20130603_b
WHERE  ex IN ( 0, 0 )
```

Gives the following plan

[image]

The table is no longer accessed and is replaced with a constant scan. To see the issue with untrusted constraints you can try.

```
/*Disable constraint*/
ALTER TABLE t20130603_b
  NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ck

/*Re-enable without checking existing data. 
Constraint is not trusted*/
ALTER TABLE t20130603_b
  CHECK CONSTRAINT ck

SELECT is_not_trusted
FROM   sys.check_constraints
WHERE  name = 'ck'

SELECT *
FROM   t20130603_b
WHERE  ex IN ( 0, 0 )
```

The above goes back to the original table scan plan.

```
/*Correct way of re-enabling constraint*/
ALTER TABLE t20130603_b
  WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ck

/*Constraint is trusted*/
SELECT is_not_trusted
FROM   sys.check_constraints
WHERE  name = 'ck'

/*Back to constant scan*/
SELECT *
FROM   t20130603_b
WHERE  ex IN ( 0, 0 )
```

After the constraint is trusted again it is back to the constant scan.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had completely forget about those (disregarding them for so long).